# Как правильно импортировать модули es6

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Я пишу приложение на реакте. Во многих модулях есть строки вида

```
import Tools from '../../../components/Tools';
```

Можно ли как-то избавиться от этих многоточий, написать что то вроде

```
import Tools from __dirname +'components/Tools'; // не работает
```

То есть как начинать поиск файлов от корня проекта?

Comment: напишите плагин для сборщика который используете. но вообще какая-то стремная идея. При таком раскладе в правильны редакторах переход по ссылкам работать не будет..

Comment: ну например можно использовать webpack->resolve->alias
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias